# Как рассчитать усредненную освещенность изображения?

Tags: шейдеры

Имеется изображение с камеры ночного видения (освещенность окружения). Также имеется карта глубины(от 0 до 1 дальности камеры).

Задача:

> Найти наиболее освещенную область на экране и выставить в данную
>   область объект цели на дистанцию по карте глубины. Если областей
>   несколько, то выбрать нечто среднее с учетом того что ближе к
>   наблюдателю объекты имеют высший приоритет.

Comment: О каких шейдерах речь?

Comment: Поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему?

Comment: Делаю все в Unity (шейдеры Cg/HLSL). Хочу сделать фейковое переотражение света для двух сближающихся динамических объектов. Для этого планирую определить область с самой яркой ближайшей освещенной поверхностью и разместить point-источник света с настроенным светом и интенсивностью между исходной фарой и найденной точкой.

Нужно очень простое решение, без сложных вычислений чтобы определить  наибольшую область способную переотражать свет от фары. Здесь нужен баланс для выбора между дальностью освещенной поверхности и яркостью цвета для ее освещения.

Comment: Не знаю как рассчитать средневзвешенное значений для переотражение таких параметров как: глубина, яркость источника, позиция на экране.